# How to develop a gradient descent for multiple variable through a for loop (without vectorization formula)?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave, linear-algebra

Hello and thanks for helping. I'm studying for the Andrew Ng's Machine Learning Class and for the second week I have to solve homework regarding gradient descent for single and multiple variables. 
I was able to code the gradient descent for single variable: however, I started to encounter multiple errors when I tried to code the gradient descent for multiple variables.

Searching online, numerous people suggested to use the following formula:

`theta = theta - (alpha/m) * (X' * (X * theta - y))`

However, because I didn't fully understand the simplification and I prefer code something that I can really master and be comfortable, I'm trying hard to write a gradient descent with multiple variables using for loop.

```
alpha = 0.01 % learning rate
m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);
for iter = 1:num_iters
   for i = 1:(size(X,2))
   theta(i) = theta(i) - alpha / m * sum((X * theta - y)) .* X(:,i);
   end
end
```

With this type of code, I get this error:

> error: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 47x1)

Is there a way to perform this gradient descent without using vectorization and with a for loop? 
If yes, what's my mistake?

Comment: For the lack of better explanation, vectorization is row-wise/column-wise parallel evaluation. So basically you need to add a loop over each column (if your variables are defined in columns and rows are you samples).

Answer (score 0):

You are making an illegal matrix multiplication.
If op1 is n*m then op2 should be m*z, and the result will be op3 n*z.